# Google Sheets, need to edit a column based on two columns on a second sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Good morning!

I've been searching high and low for how to do this, and while I *feel* like I get close I can't get anything more than 'invalid formula' from the conditional formatting in google sheets. So here's what I'm trying to do;

Column C on sheet 1 (Working List) needs to have a red background if the following conditions are met;

- Column 'P' on sheet 2 (Complete) has the 'Address Changed' option in the drop down box (its the first one on the drop down, I've been struggling to figure out if it needs to be a '0' given its position in the list or if its 'Address Changed')
- Column 'C' on sheet 2 has the same account numbers in Column 'C' on sheet 1.

I can set it up to find duplicate accounts, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the first rule for the drop down box to work. Advice?

Attempts thus far, none of them worked, all were tried separately and not in conjunction with each other. Google just says 'invalid formula' and won't save it or do anything with it.

```
=and(EQ(Complete!$O, "Address Changed"), EQ('Working List'!$C, Complete!$C))
=match($C2, indirect("Complete!$C:$C"), 0)
=if(EQ, indirect("Complete!$O, "Address Changed""), EQ('Working List'!$C, "Completed!$C"))
=and(indirect("Complete!$O:$O,$O="Address Changed""))
```

so I've tried to figure out a better way to get it working, and this is what I think might be closer to the answer.
    =and(if($O:$O,indirect("Complete!$O:$O),0)),[match($C2,indirect("Complete!$C:$C"),0)]

***Friend helped me solve this. The following worked for what I needed....

=index(indirect("Sheet2!O:O"), match(C1, indirect("Sheet2!C:C"), 0)) = "Address Changed"

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your working sheets?

Comment: Regrettably, I don't have access to them due to issues with my work computer and the restrictions my employer sets on things in regards to being able to post them onto 3rd party websites...

Comment: So, mayby build a sample based on dummy data? Now, it's hard to understand your needs...

Comment: Column 'c' on both sheets 1 and 2 are account numbers. if the 'p' column on sheet two has "Address Changed" selected in a drop down box, I need to have Column 'C' checked if the account numbers match on both sheets, and if both conditions are true, the cells should be red.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sheet with some foo data I built based on your sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RcM5WX3KWgWq-WWuPgyF-PZe3RP99qWF-IRpSr35Zik/edit?usp=sharing

I used some helper column, as you see.

- if sheet2!P1 is changed to "Address Changed" K1 will have value of 1. This is a simple `IF` function.
- if sheet2!C = sheet1!C, L will change to 1. This is another simple `ARRAYFORMULA(IF())`

Finally, column C will be formatted with the data from K1 and L by this formula 
: `=AND(L2=1, $K$2=1)`

You can then hide the helper column / cell.

If you don't want to use helper column, look at the formula in column D :

`=AND(INDIRECT("Sheet2!C2:C") = C2:C, INDIRECT("Sheet2!P1")="Address Changed")`

This will serve your purpose.

You cannot refer to another sheet directly in conditional format formula, hence if you don't want to use helper column, you will have to use INDIRECT. This is also the reason why your formula failed in the first place.

I personally wouldn't recommend you to use INDIRECT though...

Comment: Thanks, I'll reference this on monday in the office and see if it works. And yeah, I had a few moments of scratching my head trying to figure out why it didn't work before I stumbled upon indirect.